# MVC3 call controller function on dropdown select

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3

I have the following code in a partial view

```
Country Selector</label>
    @Html.DropDownListFor(model => model.CountryGroup, Model.CountryCodes, new { id = "CountryGroup", name = "country-codes" })
    @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.CountryGroup, "*")
```

In the controller I have

```
public ActionResult ProcessRemoteOrder()
    {
        var a = 1;
        return null;
    }
```

I am assuming that when the code runs a break point on var a will be hit.  it is not.
Can someone tell me where I can findout what how to get the function in the controller is run?

thnx

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to call the controller action when you select an item from the dropdown, you need to listen to the `change` event of the drop down and use jQuery ajax to make a call to the action method

```
$(function(){
  $("#CountryGroup").change(function(){
     $.get("@Url.Action("ProcessRemoteOrder","YourControllerName")",
                                                                  function(data){
         //do some thing with the response, in data variable.
     });
  });
});
```

To check whether it is running. Set a breakpoint in your code on the line you want to debug and when the code execute that line the breakpoint will be highlighted with yellow color.

Comment: Thanks for answering.So I have seen this elsewhere and tried it.  I have breakpoint in the controller function and it is never hit, even though the page does a reload.  Should the breakpoint be hit?

Comment: the page wont do a reload on the dropdown item select. If it happens, there is some other script doing that. check it in your page

Comment: So I have this in the Js ** $.get('@Url.Action("ProcessRemoteOrder","Checkout")'**, but it is rendering as ** $.get('',** - Should I not see the url rendered in the get?

Comment: If it is an external js file, you can not use the url helper methods. You need to get those path using helper methods in global js variables in your razor view file and use that variables in the external javascript